# Why doesn't the Array.filter() method only work with arrow functions, as opposed to traditional functions as well in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried running a simple test:

```js
var array = ["test", "testing", "bananas"]
var result = array.filter(function(word) { word.includes("test") } )
console.log(result)
```

That didn't work, but this did:

```js
var array = ["test", "testing", "bananas"]
var result = array.filter(word => word.includes("test") )
console.log(result)
```

I'm just curious why only arrow functions work, shouldn't an arrow function always work when a simple function does?

Any responses would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your traditional function is missing `return`

Answer (score 4):

If the function inside the filter wont return true it wont populate the array. You have to return a value depending on if the value is true/false array will be populated by filter.

```js
var array = ["test", "testing", "bananas"]
var result = array.filter(function(word) { return word.includes("test") } )
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

When using a block (`{}`) to define an arrow function body, you have to return the result **explicitly** using the `return` keyword.

Instead, if you use an arrow function, **without a block**, **the return value is implicit** and will be the last evaluated value.

This is why the following code worked:

```js
const array = ["test", "testing", "bananas"]
const result = array.filter(word => word.includes("test") )
console.log(result)
```

While this code doesn't work:

```
const array = ["test", "testing", "bananas"]
const result = array.filter(word => { word.includes("test") })
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work, you just need to `return` the result :

```js
var array = ["test", "testing", "bananas"]
var result = array.filter(function(word) {
  return word.includes("test")
})
console.log(result)
```